# How to rescind permission granted under Family Sharing/Ask to Buy

Tags: family-sharing

Using Family Sharing, I granted approval for my daughter to install an app. I now wish to rescind permission for that app, so that if she wants to download it again, it will ask me for permission again. (ie. I want to put the state back to how it was before I granted permission). How do I do this? Is there a way to manage the app approvals individually?

Comment: Ever find an answer to this?  Would like to do the same.  I tried removing and re-adding the user to the family and it didn't change anything.

Comment: I have not yet been able to discover whether this is even possible

Comment: Apple is great at designing hardware and software.  The conclusion I have come to is that this feature was "by design".